# Unique_together M2M relationship

Tags: django, unique, m2m

I have the following two models:

```
class TournamentTeam(models.Model)
    profiles = models.ManyToManyField(Profile) # Profile is my user
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='navn')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='beskrivelse')
    team_size = models.IntegerField()
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('TournamentTeam')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I would like to have the `name` and the `tournament` (autogenerated by django) on the `TournamentTeam` be `unique_together`.
I've tried simply adding:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('name', 'tournament'),)
```

Without success.
I've also tried doing it on initialization, but also without success.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._meta.unique_together = (('name', 'tournament'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

unique_together is used for model fields. 'tournament is not a field'.
Perhaps you wanted 'name' and 'teams' but that also wouldn't work because unique_together doesn't work with ManyToManyField.

Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#unique-together